# Is calling str.replace() twice the best solution for overlapping matches?

Tags: python, replace

When I execute the following code I expect all ' a ' to be replaced by ' b ' yet only non overlapping matches are replaced.

```
" a a a a a a a a ".replace(' a ', ' b ')
>>>' b a b a b a b a'
```

So I use the following:

```
" a a a a a a a a ".replace(' a ', ' b ').replace(' a ', ' b ')
>>>' b b b b b b b b '
```

Is this a bug or a feature of *replace* ?

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) *ALL OCCURENCES* are replaced.

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])

    Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: It should be "all non-overlappng occurances" but then, one could argue that once you've replaced one " a ", then next one _is_ "a " (so, not an occurance). It it was otherwise, you'd have to rescan the string a potentially infinite number of times to do replacements. Something like `"aaa".replace("a", "a")` would never end.

Comment: And as an aside, one can move to a regular expression when regular string replace doesn't work. `re.sub(r"\ba\b", "b", the_string)`. But it still would not like overlapping occurnaces.

Comment: If overlapping occurrences did get replaced, what should `" a a ".replace(' a ', '(b)')"` even return? `"(b)b)"` or `"(b(b)"` or `"(b)a "`?

Comment: @KellyBundy If replace did “double replace” I would expect `(b)(b)` in this case. I would find this more intuitive. I understand current behavior might be more logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your best bet is using regex. Lookbehind/lookahead expressions let you match part of a string surrounded by a specific expression.

```
import re

s = " a a a a a a a a "

pattern = r'(?<= )a(?= )'

print(re.sub(pattern, "b", s))
```

Spaces don't actually become part of the match, so they don't get replaced.

Comment: Thank! Definitely the rabbit hole I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

why not just replace only the thing you want to replace that is only 'a' and not  ' a ' like this

```
" a a a a a a a a ".replace('a', 'b')
```

which gives the output

```
' b b b b b b b b '
```